# How to implement Many-to-Many in Active Record models in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5, associations, model-associations

i'm doing a Rails project for school, and one of the requirements is that i use a many to many relationship in my models. The examples everywhere i look are very simple and make sense, but i just can't incorporate it into what i'm specifically doing.

The project i'm doing is a sport betting site, basically you would pick either Fighter A or Fighter B to win, and the odds would be displayed on page with a potential payout amount listed, etc.

I've created A **Fighter**, **Fight** and **Event** model so far, and getting them to work well with each other has been tough. Here's what i have:

```
class Event < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :fights
end

class Fight < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :red_corner, :class_name => "Fighter", :foreign_key => 'red_id'
  belongs_to :blue_corner, :class_name => "Fighter", :foreign_key = 'blue_id'
  belongs_to :event
end

class Fighter < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :red_corner, :class_name => "Fighter", :foreign_key => 'red_id'
  has_one :blue_corner, :class_name => "Fighter", :foreign_key => 'blue_id'
end
```

Just to expand on this in case anyone is confused, an Event holds many fights per night, let's say around 10. A Fight consists of 2 Fighters (an opponent in the red corner, and one in the blue corner, not sure if i handled the FK there properly, but i believe it works so far).

What i need is:

1. A many to many situation here that i can incorporate. Would be nice to somehow include my Event model into it so that i can return a list of fights that are on a specific Event. (Instead of loading multiple values into one column in my Event table).
2. I also wanted to use the Fights table to retrieve the Fighters' names as well, without actually saving them to the Fight model (a Fighters name is inside the Fighter model). Ex: 'Fight.find(2).Fighters.names' -- something to that effect anyway.

Can post my schema as well if need be.

Answer (score 0):

You did not mention that you cared to get the fights for a given fighter, so with that assumption, you can just get rid of everything in your Fighter model and it should work (assuming your schema is valid). (If you DID want to get all of the fights for a fighter, it would be slightly more complicated .. I can help if you really need that):

Doing this:

```
class Event < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :fights
end

class Fight < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :event
  belongs_to :red_corner, :class_name => "Fighter", :foreign_key => 'red_id'
  belongs_to :blue_corner, :class_name => "Fighter", :foreign_key => 'blue_id'
end

class Fighter < ApplicationRecord

end
```

Allows me to do:

```
fighter1 = Fighter.create(name: "Bob")
=> #<Fighter id: 1, name: "Bob", created_at: "2018-11-06 00:52:05", updated_at: "2018-11-06 00:52:05">

fighter2 = Fighter.create(name: "Jack")
=> #<Fighter id: 2, name: "Jack", created_at: "2018-11-06 00:52:06", updated_at: "2018-11-06 00:52:06">

event = Event.create(name: "Super fight day")
=> #<Event id: 1, name: "Super fight day", created_at: "2018-11-06 00:52:09", updated_at: "2018-11-06 00:52:09">

fight = event.fights.create(red_corner: fighter1, blue_corner: fighter2)
=> #<Fight id: 1, event_id: 1, red_id: 1, blue_id: 2, created_at: "2018-11-06 00:52:09", updated_at: "2018-11-06 

puts "#{Event.first.fights.first.red_corner.name} vs #{Event.first.fights.first.blue_corner.name}"
Bob vs Jack
```

Comment: Oh wow, that does work, thank you! So i really didn't need to define anything in my Fighters model? Why is that exactly? Also, anything to add pertaining to a Many to Many i could make here?

Comment: You don't need anything in the Fighter model because the relationship between Fight and Fighter is unidirectional here, with Fight as the parent, and Fighter as the child. You don't need to reference the Fight from the Fighter in your scenario, only the Fighter from the Event. Doing Fighter.first.event won't work because you haven't defined that active record relationship in Fighter. You only need to define those relationships in the models you want to add Active Record association helpers to.  Does that make sense?